# Edges in convex point sets that split the set into odd or even sets of points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove or disprove whether there exists a convex set of $2n$ points (denote this by $\mathcal{P}$) such that the following is true: we split $\mathcal{P}$ into two sets of equal cardinality, let these sets be $P_1$ and $P_2$. Now, we want $P_1$ and $P_2$ chosen in a way such that if we draw an edge from any point $p_1\in P_1$ to any $p_2\in P_2$, then this edge splits the convex point set $\mathcal{P}$ into two odd components. This property should hold for any pair $\{p_1,p_2\}$.

It seems like there is no way to choose $P_1$ and $P_2$ from $\mathcal{P}$ such that the property above holds. However, I am struggling to prove that this is actually the case.

My idea would be to just without loss of generality fix some $p_1\in P_1\subseteq \mathcal{P}$, and make sure that we place all the points in $P_2$ in a manner where drawing an edge from $p_1$ to any $p_2\in P_2$ splits $\mathcal{P}$ into two odd sets of points. However, in order to have $|P_1|=|P_2|$, it seems like we are forced to place one of the points in $P_2$ in a manner where we would be able to draw an edge between the fixed some point in $P_1$ and some point in  $P_2$ such that this edge splits $\mathcal{P}$ into two even components, which would be a contradiction. This is quite vague, and I am not sure if this reasoning makes sense / is correct.

Comment: Could you elaborate about what you mean by splits the convex point set into two odd components?  Do you mean that if you take the points on each side of the line through $p_1$ and $p_2$, the number of points on each side is odd - or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that - if the edge splits the set into two sets of odd cardinality, then these are "odd components".

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're looking for?  Perhaps with $n=2$ and $n=3$?

Answer (score 0):

Since the points are in convex position, let's label the points $\{1,\dots,2n\}$.  Let's ask the question: Which lines through point $1$ split the points into two odd sets?

The second point must also have an odd index since the number of points between $1$ and a point $p$ is $p-2$.  Therefore, there are $n-1$ lines through $1$ that split the points into two odd sets.

Suppose that $P_1$ and $P_2$ partition the points so that $1\in P_1$ and $P_1$ and $P_2$ each have $n$ points.  So, there are $n$ lines formed from $1$ to points in $P_2$, but there are not this many lines that split the points into two odd sets.

Therefore, there is always a line that splits the points into two even sets.

Comment: This is not correct. Each point is only involved in one edge.

Comment: Maybe I was not being clear or did not perhaps understand something though. You can think of the setting like it's a perfect matching.

Comment: Then, perhaps could you clarify "Now, we want $P_1$ and $P_2$ chosen in a way such that if we draw an edge from any point $p_1\in P_1$ to any $p_2\in P_2$, then this edge splits the convex point set $\mathcal{P}$ into two odd components. This property should hold for any pair $\{p_1,p_2\}$."?  In particular, it seems like you're taking all pairs of edges from points in $p_1$ to points in $p_2$.  Then, for any particular point in $P_1$, there are $n$ edges to points in $p_2$.